# C# TreeView DoubleClick WindowsForms

Tags: c#, treeview

```
private void treeView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pRetorno == true)
    {
        if (treeView.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            pOc = new OcorrenciasCategoriasDAO().Buscar(Convert.ToInt32(treeView.SelectedNode.Tag));
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Não cai no evento `DoubleClick`, clicando duas vezes em toda área do treeview e também nós.

Comment: fiz o teste aqui comigo e funcionou. Uma observação. Se o treeView estiver vazio, ou seja, sem ao menos um nó, ele não vai funcionar mesmo. É necessário ter alguma informação no treeView, ao menos uma para chamar o evento em questão.

Comment: @pnet você me marcou equivocadamente. Deveria ter marcado o OP do post.

Comment: Agora que eu vi. Deveria ser para o Marcelo Marin, desculpa-me cara, foi sem querer mesmo.